# Reverse Linked List Issue

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, java.util.scanner, ctrl

I am doing a project for school and my job is to make a LinkedList program that a user can read into a line of ints and use the Linked List functions to print them in reverse.
I have it somewhat working, however, every time I must end the read in from System.in by pressing Ctrl+C. Every... Time...

I'm trying to find a way to stop the scanner read when it reads the int -1.
Whitespace is okay as well. But once it reads -1, i want it to stop
But I cannot find the proper way.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//ReverseUsingLinkedList.java
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseUsingLinkedList
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a sequence of Integers, -1 to end: ");

        LinkedList<Integer> num= new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(keyboard.hasNext())
        {
            num.addFirst(keyboard.nextInt());
        }
        keyboard.close();
        num.removeFirst();       //Removes the -1 from the LinkedList

        System.out.println("List in reverse :" + num.toString());

    }
}
```

I have tried changing the read into hasNext.Int() instead but that cause the read to jump over every other int that I was trying to read. I also tried using an Iterator of some sort but I could not find the proper way to use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *I must end the read in from System.in by pressing Ctrl+C* - how else do you expect the scanner to know that there is no more input from System.in?  - maybe `break` if not an int ?

Comment: However in this case whitespace is okay as well, I'm trying to find a way that will stop the scanner when it reads -1. However it can't find the right way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to test if input is `-1` and to break if so

```
while(keyboard.hasNext())
  int num = keyboard.nextInt();
  if (num == -1) // or less than 0 ?
     break;    
  num.addFirst(num);
}
```

**edit**

Please note @nullpointer very valid comment

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of just initializing it to an int like that. Thank you. This helped a lot!

Comment: @Scary Wombat - this also ensures that -1 is now not added to the list and should not be removed as in the question. Plus the alternate inputs to the list.

Answer (score 1):

To use any sort of reader, you will need to iterate through the reader to record the number of objects first, and then iterate **a second time** to use the actual values. Try the following:

```
int len = 0;

while(keyboard.hasNext())
{
    len++;
}
keyboard.close();

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    int temp = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (temp == -1) 
        break;
}
```

Once you break from the `for` loop, you can choose whether you want to remove the `-1` element. The `O{n}` will be the same, except now it won't jump to every int value rather than every other.

In addition, I suggest you to try `java.io.BufferedReader` over `java.util.Scanner`. It only works if you have each int in a separate line, but the speed is over 10 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user input as a int. enclose it in a try catch block. In exception you can break.

```
try{
    int x =keyboard.nextInt();
    if(x==-1)
         break;
catch(Exception e ){
    break;
}
num.addFirst(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer from @Scary helps to check for the correct condition. 
I would suggest updating the implementation to read the next input like follows and avoid alternating the input within the list --

```
int input = keyboard.nextInt(); // the first input
while (input !=-1) { // you do not jump with a hasNext() call now
   num.addFirst(input);
   input = keyboard.nextInt(); // successive input
}
// get rid of removeFirst() call
```

---

With the above approach the input-output be like -

> ```
> Enter a sequence of Integers, -1 to end: 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> -1
> List in reverse :[6, 5, 4, 3]
> ```

---

With your current update and Scary's suggestion you might still provide n input **2, 4, 6, 7, -1** just to find the output **7 , 4** which doesn't seems to be desired.